# Oracle: Mutually modifying two tables?

Tags: oracle, trigger

Suppose I have two tables I want to keep in sync:

```
create table a(x number, s varchar2(10));
create table b(x number, s varchar2(10));
```

It's easy to keep B synchronized with A, using triggers such as:

```
create or replace trigger a_t1 
after insert on a 
for each row 
begin
  insert into b(x,s) values(:new.x,:new.s);
end;
```

Of course, if I add the inverse trigger:

```
create or replace trigger b_t1 
after insert on b 
for each row 
begin
  insert into a(x,s) values(:new.x,:new.s);
end;
```

I will get a mutating table error if I insert into either table (and which of course is the only thing that keeps the triggers from executing in an infinite cycle).

**My question**:  how can I arrange for these two tables to sync themselves, such that modifications to A are reflected in B, and vice versa, without modifying the applications that are modifying A and B?

This is for a very short-term solution, so no hack is too cheap.

(disclaimer)
I realize the horribleness of what I'm asking!  This is a short-term integration bridge and will go away as soon as integration is complete.
(end disclaimer)

Comment: And I assume there is some reason that you can't make `b` a synonym for `a` or a view on `a`?  Could `b` be a materialized view based on `a`?

Answer (score 3):

Just keep one table. Then replace the other table with a view on the table. Now you should be able to *insert*/*update*/*delete* a row in either the view or the table. Normally this should work. If the *insert*/*update*/*delete* in the view cause a problem then you can always create triggers on the view that replace *insert*, *delete*, and *update* (`create trigger t_x instead of update on view`). Check [the oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) for more information about the triggers